# Block app internet acces on Galaxy S7?

Tags: applications, samsung-galaxy-s7, firewall

Is it possible to block an app from accessing internet (both wifi and data) on Galaxy S7 with Android 8?
Without using any external firewall app.

Thanks.

Comment: With root access, run `iptables -I OUTPUT -j DROP`.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have root access on the phone.

Comment: I notice -2 on my question. Can someone help me understand what I did wrong? I want to do better in the future. Thanks.

Comment: Because what you are asking is already discussed in many questions: https://android.stackexchange.com/search?q=block+internet+access

Comment: Got it. Sorry. Hopefully better next time. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

without root access, a good firewall seems to be the only option.
i think netGuard will be good for that.

**but if it's possible, I would recommend update your android up to 9 - then, it will be simple for you to block your apps from accessing the internet.**

---

If you have a relatively new smartphone with Android 9 Pie (or newer), open Settings and go to Wireless & networks.

In the Android settings for networks and Wi-Fi, tap on Data usage. Next, tap on Network access.

Now you see a list with all your installed apps and checkmarks for their access to Mobile data and Wi-Fi. To block an app from accessing the internet, uncheck both boxes next to its name. If you want to turn off the WiFi for certain apps, uncheck the Wi-Fi box for those apps, and leave Mobile data checked.
If you tap on System apps, you are going to find out that you can block access only to Mobile data for those apps, and not to Wi-Fi.

This is a restriction designed by Google that ensures your systems apps get connected to the internet, at least when you are connected to WiFi.

When you are done blocking apps from accessing the internet, close the Settings. When you use an Android app which has its internet access blocked, you see a notification like the one below. Do not tap Remove because you are going to remove this restriction.

Comment: Hi, I am assuming Galaxy S7 can't be upgraded to Android 9.0 in any way right?

Comment: Well...The S7 will not get Android 9 Pie from Samsung officially. :( If you want Pie, you need a custom unofficial ROM, but that's the beauty of Android.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I am assuming that will permanently and irrevocably disable Samsung Pay, right? Just want to clarify.